# with-temp-buffer removes text properties

Tags: font-lock, text-properties

Given e.g. `(with-temp-buffer (clojure-mode) (insert ":hello") (buffer-string))`, I'd expected the result to be propertized, however it isn't.

How to get a propertized string out of a temporary buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaken.  `with-temp-buffer` does not remove text properties.

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert (propertize ":hello" 'face 'error))
  (buffer-string))

=> #(":hello" 0 6 (face error))
```

I think you're expecting the call to `clojure-mode` to cause the subsequent *non-propertized* text to instantaneously acquire text properties as it is inserted into the buffer, which is not the case.  (It may *seem* instant when you are entering text interactively, but that's just because humans are very slow.)

Assuming you want to force `font-lock-mode` to process the buffer before obtaining the buffer string, use `font-lock-ensure`:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (clojure-mode)
  (insert ":hello")
  (font-lock-ensure)
  (buffer-string))
```